# How to make font-size proportional to its input's height in css?

Tags: html, css, input, height, font-size

I have an input which is set to 50% of its parent's height but I can't get font-size to match.
I hoped something like `font-size: 100%` would work but it doesn't. I don't need font-size to be exactly 100% of input's height I just want to make font-size proportional to the input's height.

Ideal solution for me would be to have font-size defined using input's or parent element's height. Is there some trick to achieve this? I have looked at every unit and all seem to be relative to viewport size or other font-sizes

**My attempt:**

```
.input {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  font-size: 100%; //<- doesn't work - if I inspect input's height and put its actual px value here it will match but it is obviously not dynamic as I have to manually check px value
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

**What I have:**
[image: current state]
**What I am trying to get:**
[image: desired state]

Comment: Font-size:72px may work best for you, or you can adjust according to your wish.

Comment: could you try with font-size: 10vh or the % you wish? [source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Comment: Ideally I would like font-size to adjust based on input's height automatically. So I don't have to hardcode any values using media screens.